# Rank values of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have this input of array: `int[] input = {1,3,2,2,33,1};` I need to make score for it like this output: `{1,3,2,2,4,1}` so the smallest number gets 1 and if there is smaller it gets 2 an so on.
another example: for input `{1,10,3,44,5,2,5}` -outputs-> `{1,5,3,6,4,2,4}`

This is my try but it does not work as expected.

```
  public static int[] getRanksArray(int[] array) {
    int[] result = new int[array.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] != array[i]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        result[i] = count + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: array[j] < array[i] ?

Comment: i am getting --> `1,5,3,3,6,1,`

Comment: Why are `33` and `44` not there in your output? I could not understand your question. **Note:** I am not the downvoter of your question.

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash its like ranking

Comment: All your code does is check for duplicates, then assign `result` indices to however many duplicates there were (plus 1). It doesn't seem you've tried to implement any ranking logic.

Comment: I would suggest you first sort your input. This has 2 advantages, the first being that you need to know what the smallest value is to assign 1 to it. The second being that is easier now to assign scores to each value. For example if the smallest value is 3 and the 2nd smallest is 44 then you wouldn't immediately know that there is no 4, 5, etc. So when it is sorted you would actually be able to assign score starting at 1 and increment if the next value is different from the previous.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash He wants to create a copy of the array, but where each number is replaced with it's "rank" (if 10 is the 4th highest number available, all 10s should be replaced with 4s)

Comment: Also a tip when posting algorithmic question like this, also add your precondifitions clearly. My solution (mentioned in the previous comment) only is appropriate if it's ok to have the array sorted and return a sorted score array.

Comment: I would first sort the input array (going from small to large or vice versa, depending on how you want the ranks), then loop through it putting the 'rank' into the result array and increasing the 'count' by one each time the value is larger/smaller than the previous value in the input array.

Comment: @Svenpegels could you please release your idea? its not a problem if the array is sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: Updated to handle double rather than int input array.

First sort an array representing indices of the input array. Then walk through this array incrementing a rank counter whenever you encounter successive elements that are not equal ([ideone](https://ideone.com/en4XlK))

```
public static int[] rank(double[] nums)
{
  Integer[] idx = new Integer[nums.length];
  for(int i=0; i<idx.length; i++) idx[i] = i;

  Arrays.sort(idx, (a, b) -> (Double.compare(nums[a], nums[b])));

  // Or use this for descending rank
  // Arrays.sort(idx, (a, b) -> (Double.compare(nums[b], nums[a])));

  int[] rank = new int[nums.length];
  for(int i=0, j=1; i<idx.length; i++) 
  {
    rank[idx[i]] = j;
    if(i < idx.length - 1 && nums[idx[i]] != nums[idx[i+1]]) j++;
  }
  return rank;
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rank(new double[] {1,3,2,2,33,1})));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rank(new double[] {1,10,3,44,5,2,5})));
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 3, 6, 4, 2, 4]
```

Comment: @Thanks, i like this solution. Any way to get rid of this Arrays.toString wrapper please?

Comment: The use of Arrays.toString is really just a cheap way of obtaining a printable representation of the array. You could assign the result of calling `rank` to an `int[]` variable and do what you want with it - including printing the elements one by one. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Thank you  i am now release that my input array is array of double, could you please change your solution accordantly ? so instead of this input-> `{1,3,2,2,33,1}` i have `{1.0,3.0,2.0,2.0,33.0,1.0}`

Comment: sure, I've updated the answer to deal with an array of doubles.

Comment: Really? I still get the output shown in the answer. I've added a link to the code at [ideone](https://ideone.com/en4XlK) for you to try it there.

Comment: What is need is like this input: `{1.0,0.82,0.75,0.75}` with your algo. i am getting this [3, 2, 1, 1] what i need is [1,2,3,3]

Comment: You want the ranks in descending order? The example input & output in your original question ask for ascending order. I've updated the answer to show the change you'd need to make to get descending order.

Comment: Can i please connect with you about another problem? i would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using a sorted map storing lists/sets of indexes mapped by the values of the input array.

Then you can iterate over this map and fill the rank array with incrementing indexes.

Implementation:

```
    public static int[] rank(int[] arr) {
        TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            List<Integer> indexes = map.compute(arr[i], (k, v) -> v == null ? new ArrayList<>() : v);
            indexes.add(i);
            map.putIfAbsent(arr[i], indexes);
        }
        int[] rank = new int[arr.length];
        int id = 1;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            for(Integer i : entry.getValue()) {
                rank[i] = id;
            }
            id++;           
        }

        return rank;
    }
```

Test:

```
int[][] d = {
    {1,3,2,2,33,1},
    {1,10,3,44,5,2,5}
};

for (int[] input : d) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rank(input)));
}
```

output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 3, 6, 4, 2, 4]
```